# Error handling when wrong type(class) of input to the function argument in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class named Fruit contains some functions:

```
Class Fruit {
      Fruit(); //some constructer 
      int countFruit(Fruit n); //some function
}
```

Let's say i have another class named *Vegetable* constructed in the same fashion as Fruit. In the function **int Fruit::countFruit(Fruit input)**, i'm only allowing variable with class *Fruit* to be a valid input, if user accidentally throw in a variable with class *Vegetable*, the function should be able to detect that and cout << "wrong input".

Question is, how should i write my function?

```
int Fruit::countFruit(Fruit n){
if () // i want to say if n is not class Fruit
   cout << "wrong input";
```

Comment: You can have another function named `int countFruit(Vegetable n);` and handle that separately.

Comment: But I still think you are having wrong imagination/approach in terms of C++

Comment: Give a proper example.  You talk about having some form of class hierarchy, yet you show only a single class.  Maybe learn about how to use overloading, inheritance and polymorphism in C++ _first_, before trying to solve whatever problem you are currently facing.

Comment: @paddy, I'm trying to produce a minimal reproducible example here but guess i'm not doing a good job. As described in my question, i might have other Class in my program, for example Class Vegetable{}, Class Meat{}, etc. Let say the user defined a variable of Class Vegetable, and accidentally throw that into the countFruit function. I'm thinking of how to handle that part. Is my question valid or?

Comment: No, it makes no sense in the context of your question, unless at a _stretch_ you derive all these from some common base class such as `Organic`.  But then, you are passing `Fruit` _by value_ into this function, so even if `Fruit` and `Vegetable` share a common base class, passing `Vegetable` here would be a compile error unless `Vegetable` is be implicitly convertible to `Fruit`.  And if that's the case it would be converted and _actually be_ a `Fruit`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this; I'd rather know at compile time when a function is being used incorrectly.  But to answer the question, you can just overload the `countFruit` method.

```
Class Fruit {
      Fruit(); //some constructer 
      int countFruit(Fruit n); //some function
      int countFruit(vegetable n); // overloaded function
}

int Fruit::countFruit(vegetable n){
    cout << "wrong input";
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Another possible approach is to declare `template <class T> int countFruit(T n);` and then add a specialization for `Fruit`.  This would provide an error at compile time instead.

Comment: Thanks Christian for your answer, which is simple to understand. However, i might have more Class in my program, say Class Algae{}, Class Bryophyte{}, Class Pteridophyte{}, Class Gymnosperm{} etc. Since i'm only allowing Class Fruit variable to be valid type of argument for the countFruit function, does that mean i have to write overload function for all other possible classes which deem to be invalid input? Not sure if this is the only way? thanks

Comment: Ask yourself what actual _meaning_ lies behind a non-static member function `countFruit`.  This function should query some information from a single `Fruit`.  If it's intended to count something in, say, a _collection_ of "stuff", then the function is semantically out of place and it's not surprising that it's causing general confusion.